# Accesing the values of data received

Tags: angular

How do i access the values of data i received in console?

How do i access the title of both the array elements here ?
I have to filter the list acc. to the title of all array elements so i need to access all title of elements
Here is the ss of console

https://ibb.co/tq8K67k

component.ts file

```
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('f') searchform:NgForm
onsubmit(){

}
search=''
itemlist

onclick(){
this.search=this.searchform.value
this.itemlist=this.prservice.getallproducts()
console.log(this.itemlist)


}





headElements = ['S.No' ,'Title', 'Price'];




 listofproducts
 productreceived

constructor(private prservice:Productservice,private 
route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.listofproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts()

}
onclickedit(id){
// console.log(id)
this.router.navigate([id],{relativeTo:this.route})

}


 }
```

service.ts file

```
export class Productservice{
updatedproduct=new BehaviorSubject<any>(1)
card=new Subject<any>()
cards=[]

addtocards(value){
    this.cards.push(value)
}
getallproducts(){
    return this.cards
}

getproductbyid(id){
    return this.cards[id]
}

updateproduct(id,product){
    this.cards[id]=product
    // console.log(this.cards[id])
    this.updatedproduct.next(this.cards[id])
}
deleteproduct(id){
    alert('Are you sure you want to delete this product permanently 
? Once deleted will not revert back')
    this.cards.splice(id,1)
    this.updatedproduct.next(this.cards)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if 'id' is a unique field, then map title to id and use it to filter.

in component.ts file:

```
titleList: Array<string> = [];

ngOnInit() {
this.listofproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts()
Object.values(listofproducts).forEach(prod => {
this.titleList[prod['id]] = prod['title'];
});
```

Now let's consider a data from your screenshot.

```
{title: bread,.... id:'32'}
{title: bread123,.... id:'38'}
```

When you console.log(titleList) after the code runs, you will get something like this:

```
[ '32' : 'bread',
  '38' : 'bread123' ]
```

Hence, now you can access/filter title with id in your html/ts.